# firebase service class in swift 5.1 Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I created **firebase service class**. In this class there is function `getAllCategoryData()` which fetch all data from firebase.

```
class FirebaseService
{

    static public func getAllCategoryData(completion: @escaping ([CategoryModel]) ->Void )
{
    var catModel = [CategoryModel]()
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    catModel.removeAll()
    databaseRef.child("Category").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { (dataSnapshot) in
        if let snapShot = dataSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
        {
            for snap in snapShot
            {
                if let allData = snap.value as? [String:String]
                {
                    let catName = allData["categoryName"]
                    let catImage = allData["categoryImage"]
                    catModel.append(CategoryModel(catName: catName!, catImg: catImage!))
                    //print("catName == \(catName!)")
                }
            }

        }
        print(catModel)
        completion(catModel)
    }
   }
 }
```

in this function i'm trying to fetch all category data like **categoryName &  categoryImage**.
and trying to store this data in my **CategoryModel class**

```
class CategoryModel
{ 
   var categoryName : String?
   var categoryImage : String

   init(catName : String, catImg : String) {
      self.categoryName = catName
      self.categoryImage = catImg
   }
}
```

in my **HometableVC** i'm calling this fuction like this and appending all is data to my `var data = [CategoryModel]()`. so i can show this CategoryModel array to my tableview. but its giving me **nil**.

```
FirebaseCommon.getAllCategoryData { (category) in
        self.data.append(contentsOf: category)
    }
    print("======\(data.last?.categoryName)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any usage of the data will have to happen within the closure:

```
FirebaseCommon.getAllCategoryData { (category) in
    self.data.append(contentsOf: category)
    print("======\(data.last?.categoryName)")
}
```

Comment: So how can i gonna use that array to show in table view

Comment: To refresh the table view after updating its data you're looking for something like `self.tableView.reloadData()`.